# Issue were the data is not showing up because of incorrect date and time format

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am having issue were data does not want to show up because I can't figure the format for
 2014-12-12 07:31:11.827 not sure how to write it anyone have any ideas?

```
 require_once("../../db_connect.php");

//prepared statement with PDO to query the database
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status='Received' 
AND priority='High'AND date_requested=CAST(GETDATE() AS Date) ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: also the system auto fills the date with datetime in sql. I selected datetime as datatype

Comment: GETDATE gets the current timestamp according to the server.

Comment: Are you trying to query for requests where status equals "Received", priority="High" and date requested equals today?  Is date_requested a datetime field? or a date field?

Comment: date_requested is datetime field. yes on all the queries

Comment: I tried this ("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE  status='Received' AND priority='High' AND date_requested=CAST(GETDATE() AS Time)"); but this didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways around this.   Try replacing this:

```
date_requested=CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)
```

with this:

```
DATEDIFF(dd,date_requested,GETDATE()) = 0
```

Comment: I tried it but stil no data. I am trying to get the datetime, status and priority. When I take of datetime it works. I need to get the current date of the record and it is mssql

Comment: If you are using my suggestion correctly, then the problem is something else.  Maybe you don't have any data in the table that matches the criteria.  Try just "SELECT * FROM requests" and see if you get any data that has status 'Received', priority 'High', and date_requested is today's date.